# Футер перекрывает контент при ресайзе окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Есть футер:

```
<footer>
<div class="row" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; text-align: right; width: 100%; padding: 15px">
Text
</div>
</footer>
```

При ресайзе окна данный футер перекрывает контент окна логина[image: trouble]

Пробовал фиксить изменением свойства position, но тогда футер начинает отображаться с середины страницы, сразу после окончания контента

Comment: Разметку со стилями для поля с авторизацией добавьте,думаю здесь нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: Попробую, но мы используем бутстрап и поэтому очень большое количество кода и стилей

Answer (score 1):

Проблему удалось решить добавлением css

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
```

и снятием стиля height 100% с тега html